# Google Pay Autofill won't work on chrome mobile

Tags: stripe-payments, google-pay, mobile-chrome

When I use chrome, google pay automatically suggests I pay using one of my saved cards.

This is working for my site on desktop but on mobile it is not.

1. It asks me to select my card
2. then to put in my CCV code
3. it then checks that it is correct
4. but it does not appear on the form when the google pay box disappears.

Is there a way to fix this or to disable google pay from suggesting using saved credit cards?

The site is live here: https://www.ticketglen.com/events/627169277aa4727312497eaf

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this by upgrading to the latest version of react.

I was using  version "^16.9.0" when there was a problem.

There is no problem with version "^18.1.0"